# PHP Shorthand ternary operator "?:" Parse error unexpected ":"

Tags: php, syntax, ternary-operator, php-5.2

I've just uploaded some old PHP files to a new server and am getting parse errors (Unexpected ':') on shorthand ternary ops. eg:

```
$y = $x ?: "Some default";
```

php version is 5.2.16 The code is littered with these shorthand ?:, so before changing them all I thought I'd see if anyone knows anything about this as I've not used PHP for a while now.

Comment: "old PHP files to a new server"-  I think you mean, "new PHP files to an old server"! (The PHP syntax used here is newer than the version of PHP installed on your (old) server.)

Comment: Why does everyone call this expression ternary operator? It only takes two arguments. Isn't this [Elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator)?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This is only available since PHP 5.3

> <sub>The expression *(expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3)* evaluates to expr2 if expr1 evaluates to **TRUE**, and expr3 if expr1 evaluates to **FALSE**.</sub>
>
> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression *expr1 ?: expr3* returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to **TRUE**, and expr3 otherwise.<sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)</sup>

See [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#example-104) for more context.

or a more useful but note in the comments:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php#102060

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php</sub>

Comment: Incorrect, I'm using PHP 5.2.x and it's working fine. See Nightwolf's answer below...

Comment: Nope, it can`t be PHP 5.2.x. Maybe in your PHP version work this `$a = $foo ? 'foo' : 'bar'` ?

Comment: The shorthand for PHP 5.2.x requires the empty value as in my answer below, but the above should work fine in PHP 5.3 .

Comment: (For Googlers in a hurry: philm and Nightwolf were wrong, and the PHP manual was right. ;) Nightwolf eventually corrected himself at/below his answer.)

Comment: I would like to add the following: if `expr1` evaluates to `true`, the *result* of that evaluation is returned. In other words, if `expr1` is true-ish, it will not be evaluated again, but the result of the expression will be used as when it was first evaluated.

Answer (score -2):

Since you are using php 5.2.16, your ternary requires 2 options e.g

```
$y = $x ? $x : "Some default";
```

Variable = condition ? true value : false value ;

Comment: PHP 5.2.x requires this syntax, but the original question's syntax works fine in 5.3.

Comment: This is wrong. This is whether a *shorthand* ternary, nor is it equivalent of what the user wants. The equivalent in PHP 5.2 would be `$y = $x ? $x : 'default';`.

Comment: @igorw: I only told the user why he is getting the error in order for him to learn, not to blindly copy code.

Comment: To re-iterate, the short-hand `?:` is only available in 5.3+

Comment: @Nightwolf that's not _shorthand_, that's the _full_ ternary operator. It seems you were getting confused because the ternary operator itself is a short version of if/else, but this question is about the shorthand ternary operator, and you're just talking about the standard ternary operator. Sorry to address such an old answer but it seems no one managed to clear up your confusion at the time.

Comment: @Niall When I wrote the answer I only knew and confirmed the requirements of the shortened "if/else" in that php version and believed it to be called shorthand. Changed to say ternary instead of shorthand.