# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'

Tags: php, ternary-operator

For long time I used something like this :

```
$foo = $foo ?: $bar; // similar to $foo = $foo ? $foo : $bar;
```

and it worked good.

but now I am on a new hosting with `PHP` Version of `5.2.17` and when I try to run similar code it shows a parse error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /../
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: C# does not allow the shorter syntax in your example.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk this is PHP, not C#

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277222/php-shorthand-ternary-operator-parse-error-unexpected

Comment: @John I known, so appreciate the liberty you have with PHP! Different versions of PHP, different degrees of freedom, shuffle a bit here and there and suddenly a bool is a string and used as a decimal! PHP is great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shortened ternary syntax is only available in [PHP 5.3 and newer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: thanks! I have updated PHP version to 5.3 and it works. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Please note that the ternary operator is a statement, and that it
doesn't evaluate to a variable, but to the result of a statement. This
is important to know if you want to return a variable by reference.
The statement return $var == 42 ? $a : $b; in a return-by-reference
function will therefore not work and a warning is issued in later PHP
versions.

So there is a problem with the return-by-reference for the ?: syntax.
That's way I explicitly wrote what should be returned.
```

Reference site https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/doctrine-user/qbSAvaKH5uI/DF_2XSxFvG4J

I can't say there was a `bug` with it, but from the url https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60169 it seems a `bug`

```
there is also segfault in (***)?:value notation.
like:
   <?php
     $str = array('test');
     list($a, $b) = is_array($str)?:$str;

and this make *the patch doesn't work* (a memory leak)
```