# Loop throught json object php

Tags: php, json

this is my code , and I am trying to loop through this json, so what I want to do is when `isset($_GET['latest=1']))` it should show one object from json above, if latest=15 it should show 15 objects, how can I do that

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if(isset($_GET['latest']))
echo 
'
    {
        "contacts": [
            {
                    "id": "c200",
                    "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                    "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "url": "http://149.202.196.143:8000/live/djemal/djemal/592.ts"
            },
            {
                    "id": "c201",
                    "name": "Johnny Depp",
                    "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "url":"http://149.202.196.143:8000/live/djemal/djemal/592.ts" 
            },
            {
                    "id": "c202",
                    "name": "Leonardo Dicaprio",
                    "email": "leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",


    "url":"http://149.202.196.143:8000/live/djemal/djemal/592.ts" 
            }
        ]
    }
';
```

Comment: Where do you take data - from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you convert your data into an array and then re-encode after you have sorted your data.

The following below maybe of some help:

**URL:**

```
http://localhost/index.php?latest=2
```

**Code - Part 1:**

This is a copy of your JSON data above.

```
$json = ' {
        "contacts": [
            {
                    "id": "c200",
                    "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                    "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "url": "http://149.202.196.143:8000/live/djemal/djemal/592.ts"
            },
            {
                    "id": "c201",
                    "name": "Johnny Depp",
                    "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "url":"http://149.202.196.143:8000/live/djemal/djemal/592.ts" 
            },
            {
                    "id": "c202",
                    "name": "Leonardo Dicaprio",
                    "email": "leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",


    "url":"http://149.202.196.143:8000/live/djemal/djemal/592.ts" 
            }
        ]
    }';
```

**Code - Part 2:**

```
$count = (isset($_GET['latest']) && filter_var($_GET['latest'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) && $_GET['latest'] >= 1) ? $_GET['latest'] : 1; //To ensure the GET is an INT and set a default value of 1.
$output = json_decode($json, TRUE); //Convert to array
$newArr = []; //Placeholder for new array

for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { //Dependent on value (1 being default) 

   if(isset($output['contacts'][$i])) { //Just incase you get an undefined index issue

       $newArr[] = $output['contacts'][$i]; 

   } else {

       break; //Break Loop if undefined
   }
}     

echo json_encode($newArr); //Finally output new array as JSON
```

**Output (For value of 2):**

```
[{
    "id": "c200",
    "name": "Ravi Tamada",
    "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
    "gender": "male",
    "url": "http:\/\/149.202.196.143:8000\/live\/djemal\/djemal\/592.ts"
}, {
    "id": "c201",
    "name": "Johnny Depp",
    "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
    "gender": "male",
    "url": "http:\/\/149.202.196.143:8000\/live\/djemal\/djemal\/592.ts"
}]
```

*Added:*
*Also added a break in case they ask for a value which is not defined in your array.*

Note:

Shorthand ternary will only work with PHP 5.3 so I suspect your error is to do with this. [PHP Shorthand ternary operator "?:" Parse error unexpected ":"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277222/php-shorthand-ternary-operator-parse-error-unexpected)

Comment: i tried but this is my error

Comment: Kindly share your error please. Please ensure that your JSON data is being set as the variable `$json`. I'll update my answer to explain.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /srv/disk14/2280797/www/rido.sportsontheweb.net/webi/api.php on line 25

Comment: thank you very much, its all ok , works perfect, how to mark this annswer correct